# Allauth - How to disable reset password for social accounts?

Tags: django, django-allauth

I want social users are only able to login without password. Therefore, I want to disable password reset at /accounts/password/reset/ for social users.

I know that I need to add a conditional in this code at allauth.accounts.forms.py

```py
class ResetPasswordForm(forms.Form):

    email = forms.EmailField(
        label=_("E-mail"),
        required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"type": "email", "size": "30"}))

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        email = get_adapter().clean_email(email)
        self.users = filter_users_by_email(email)
        if not self.users.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("The e-mail address is not assigned"
                                          " to any user account"))
        return self.cleaned_data["email"]
```

I'm thinking about this solution, but I don't know how to do it properly:

```
  elif SocialAccount.objects.filter(provider='facebook'):
      raise forms.ValidationError(_("You are using a social account.")
```

Comment: Do you have ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL=True in your system (by default it's True)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allauth extendability is not a problem. `self.users` contain all users with provided email but if you have setting `ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL=True` or just didn't change it (so it's `True` by default) then you can take just first user. Every user contain `socialaccount_set` related manager. So we just filter that set by `provider` name and if there is any item then this user has related socialaccount. So you can inherit allauth form and put additional check there:

```
# forms.py
class MyResetPasswordForm(ResetPasswordForm):
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        email = get_adapter().clean_email(email)
        self.users = filter_users_by_email(email)
        if not self.users.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("The e-mail address is not assigned"
                                          " to any user account"))
        # custom code start
        elif self.users.first().socialaccount_set.filter(provider='facebook').exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("You are using a social account.")
        # custom code end
        return self.cleaned_data["email"]
```

And then override allauth settings to use your form in their reset password view:

```
# your settings
ACCOUNT_FORMS = {
    'reset_password': 'your_app.forms.MyResetPasswordForm'
}
```

I have not tested this code so it can contain typos so feel free to post any further questions.

Comment: Hey, It works, now social users are not able to reset password. 
But could you help me to understand this?

What do you mean by
**taking first user**?

Comment: @HereHere I meant that `self.users` can contain several users if you allowed to register with the same email (defined `ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL=False`). But I think that you didn't so all your users have unique emails so it's okay to take just first user from `self.users` using `first()` method and check only it.

Answer (score 1):

[@bellum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1506264/bellum) answer is kind off right but now Allauth return a list on `filter_users_by_email(email)`

So this worked for me

```
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm, LoginForm, ResetPasswordForm
from allauth.account.adapter import get_adapter
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from allauth.account.utils import filter_users_by_email

class MyResetPasswordForm(ResetPasswordForm):
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        email = get_adapter().clean_email(email)
        self.users = filter_users_by_email(email)
        if not self.users:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("Unfortunately no account with that"
                                          " email was found"))
        # custom code start
        elif self.users[0].socialaccount_set.filter(provider='google').exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("Looks like the email/password combination was not used. Maybe try Social?"))
            # custom code end
        return self.cleaned_data["email"]
```

Note: I am using google social authentication if you are using Facebook then change it to facebook.